# Java generics: type is bound by unimplemented interface

Tags: java, generics

I'm reading java docs on generics. On that page https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html error in code:

```
public static <T> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray)
        if (e > elem)  // compiler error
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

Is corrected to:

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
    public int compareTo(T o);
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray)
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

And I do not see implementation of `Comparable<T>` interface on the page. My guess it should be implemented, just it's left out as obvious. Is my guess correct?

Comment: Because `Comparable` is built-in, part of the Java Runtime Library. See javadoc at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood your question, so: *"implementation of Comparable<T> interface"* You can't see implementation since the implementation will be part of the class that `T` represents, whatever that will be. If you want to see an example, you just need to find any class that implements `Comparable`, such as `String`, `Integer`, `LocalDateTime`, ... If you look at the source code of any such class, you'll see *an* implementation of the `compareTo` method. Every class that implements `Comparable` will likely have its own separate implementation. There is no single implementation to look at

Comment: @Andreas, thank you. My question was if code on docs page was fully working. If Comparable is built-in, why then they wrote its *definition* there, not posting link to actual one?

Comment: Likely as a *convenience* for you, so you didn't have to go look elsewhere.

Comment: @Andreas, I see now `T` will implement it. Would code be fine if instead of `Comparable` which is built-in it was written something user-made, like `foo-inteface`?

Comment: Any class that declares that it implements an interface must implement the methods of the interface, whether the interface is built-in or custom. There is nothing special about built-in interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

`Comparable` interface should be implemented by class(es) `T` for which method `countGreaterThan` will be used.